# Include slashes and parentheses in tokens

Tags: whoosh

#### Background

I have search indexes containing Greek characters. Many people don't know how to type Greek so they enter something called "beta-code". Beta-code can be converted into Greek. For example, beta-code "NO/MOU" would be converted to "νόμου". Characters such as a slash or parenthesis is used to indicate an accent.

#### Desired Behavior

I want users to be able to search using either beta-code or text in the Greek script. I figured out that the Whoosh [Variations](http://pythonhosted.org/Whoosh/api/query.html#whoosh.query.Variations) class provides the mechanism I need and it almost solves my problem.

#### Problem

The Variation class works well except for when a slash or a parenthesis are used to indicate an accent in a users' query. The problem is the query are parsed such that the the special characters used to denote the accent result in the words being split up. For example, a search for "NO/MOU" results in the Variations class being asked to find variations of "no" and "mou" instead of "NO/MOU".

#### Question

Is there a way to influence how the query is parsed such that slashes and parentheses are included in the search words (i.e. that a search for "NO/MOU" results in a search for a token of ""NO/MOU" instead of "no" and "mou")?

Answer (score 1):

The search parser uses a Tokenizer class for breaking up the search string into individual terms. Whoosh will use the class that is associated with the schema. For example, the case below, the SimpleAnalyzer() will be used when searching the "content" field.

```
Schema( verse_id = NUMERIC(unique=True, stored=True),
        content  = TEXT(analyzer=SimpleAnalyzer()) )
```

By default, the SimpleAnalyzer() uses the following regular expression to tokenize search terms: "\w+(.?\w+)*"

To use a different regular expression, assign the first argument to the SimpleAnalyzer to another regular expression. For example, to include beta-code characters (slashes, parentheses, etc.) in tokens, use the following SimpleAnalyzer:

```
SimpleAnalyzer( rcompile(r"[\w/*()=\+|&']+(\.?[\w/*()=\+|&']+)*") )
```

Searches will now allow terms to include the special beta-code characters and the Variations class will be able to convert the term to the unicode version.